# How to get the exact "constraint name" from SQLException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Is there a way to get the exact "constraint name"\"index name" from C# "Microsoft SQL Exception", Error number 2601 or 2627, but without parsing the text of the "Message property"?

For example:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   switch (e.Number)
   {
      case 2601:
         /* Here i want to know the constraint name in case i have 
            more than one on a specific table, so i will be able to 
            display the correct error message to the user. 

          For example: 

          case IX_Username:
           throw new Exception("Username duplication")
          case IX_PhoneNumber:
           throw new Exception("PhoneNumber duplication")  

        */
         break;
      default:
         throw;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Sadly gotta parse...

Comment: Is it not possible to execute a query to check for duplicates rather than resorting to a constraint violation?

Comment: User1620220, Its possible but as far as i understand, it will not be good on high database load due to "Race condition" issue and preference.

Comment: You would need to execute the query and the insert/update commands within a transaction with an appropriate isolation level to eliminate the race condition.

Comment: Unless you've been rather peverse in the naming of your constraints, a simple `string.Split()` on the message text using `"` and then taking the second element in the result should always give you the constraint name (unless you have an example where that doesn't work)

Comment: @user1620220 - Can you share an example for query with the appropriate isolation level to avoid any chance of "race condition" ? (Check if row is exists, if not, insert the new row)

Comment: Inside a transaction, first execute one or more `SELECT ... FROM table (WITH UPDLOCK)` queries to check if username or phone number exists. Then do your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` command. No updates can occur on the table until you commit the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use naming convention for constraints e.g. name these to always contain underscore like `FK_Xxx` or `UQ_Xxx` then use regex to parse errors for names like this

```
    var match = Regex.Matches("Foreign key FK_Xxx violation.", @"\b\w*_\w*\b")
        .Cast<Match>().FirstOrDefault();
    return match != null ? match.Value : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the exact "constraint name"\"index name" from C#
>   "Microsoft SQL Exception", Error number 2601 or 2627, but without
>   parsing the text of the "Message property"?

**No, there is no such way.**

Comment: So can you please suggest the best way to handle that error on very loaded database with lots of queries per second?

Pleae take into the account the "Race condition" issue.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the error have a text simil to (restriction between quote):

*Infracción de la restricción UNIQUE KEY '**CIF  duplicado no admitido**'. No se puede insertar una clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.GASTOS_Proveedores'. El valor de la clave duplicada es (asd).*

you can find first and second quote and extract the message:

**CIF  duplicado no admitido**

```
    create function GetRestictionError(@MensajeError nvarchar(255))
returns nvarchar(255)
as
begin
declare @Msg nvarchar(255)

set @Msg = @MensajeError 

declare @PrimCom int
declare @SecondCom int
--asci 39+   '
set @PrimCom  = charindex(char(39),@MensajeError)
if @PrimCom > 0
    begin
        set @SecondCom = charindex(char(39),@MensajeError+1, @Primcom + 1)
        if @SecondCom > 0 
            set @Msg = SUBSTRING(@mensajeerror,@primcom+1,@secondcom - @primcom - 1)
    end 

return @Msg 
end
```

and then, use when you need. Sample:

```
begin catch
   /*SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
        */

    declare @Titulo nvarchar(255)
    set @Titulo = dbo.GetRestictionError(ERROR_MESSAGE())
    if @Titulo = '' set @Titulo = 'Error al guardar'
    select 0 as Respuesta, ERROR_MESSAGE() as Registro, @Titulo as titulo -- ERROR_PROCEDURE () as Titulo
end catch
```