# How to get primay key constraint name from sql server using java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Suppose for the following table I want to get the primary key constraints name which is `uapplication_pkey`

```
CREATE TABLE application
(
  applicationid integer NOT NULL,
  screatedby character varying(255),
  screatedon timestamp without time zone,
  sfwversion integer,
  smodifiedby timestamp without time zone,
  smodifiedon character varying(255),
  stenantid character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT uapplication_pkey PRIMARY KEY (applicationid)
)
```

I have taken help from this [How to get the exact "constraint name" from SQLException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424744/how-to-get-the-exact-constraint-name-from-sqlexception)

But not able to find the solution.

Comment: You can access information about the database itself (metadata) through [`java.sql.connection#getMetaData()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData%28%29). This will allow you to examine constraints, keys, columns, tables, etc. using the methods of [`java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).  Posted as a comment because it's just a couple of links and I don't have time right now to write up some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DatabaseMetadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) interface.

```
DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
```

Example:

```
DatabaseMetaData meta=conn.getMetaData();
rs= meta.getTables(null, null, tablename, new String[]{"TABLE"});
rs=meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, null, tablename);
while(rs.next())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have a single constraint in the table, I think this could help:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ConstraintName
FROM sys.objects
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)='application' AND type = 'PK'
```

If not, just try another way to access that table.

In order to customize your query as you want you can check this [SYS.OBJECTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx). It'll be very helpful for sure ;)

Comment: will also work if there are any number of constraints, triggers, .. on the table because with  <   type = 'PK'    > this query will always return 0 or 1 record (as it's only possible to have 0 or 1 PrimaryKey Constraint per Table)

Comment: @CeOnSql, right, thanks for the edition and suggest ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a system stored procedure that may help you:

```
EXEC sp_pkeys 'application'
```

This will return a resultset with the columns:

- TABLE_QUALIFIER
- TABLE_OWNER
- TABLE_NAME
- COLUMN_NAME
- KEY_SEQ
- PK_NAME

where PK_NAME should be the name of your PK-Constraint